# Google Sheets Query Coalesce?

Tags: google-sheets

is there any query syntax that woks like coalesce in google sheets?

if i have a source like pict below

[image]

the result i want is only getting id and time if status is true, but the time is only exist in one col either in **check column** or **report column**

so the result would be like this...

[image]

I tired this but doesn't work

```
=QUERY(A1:D4, "SELECT A, COALESCE(B, C) WHERE D = TRUE")
```

any ideas or workarounds?
Thanks

Comment: It appears not.  It's quite a cut-down set of SQL syntax https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IF(D2:D=TRUE, {A2:A, IF(B2:C="",,"×"&B2:C), D2:D}, ), 9^9, 
 COLUMNS(A:C))),, 9^9)), "×")))
```

Answer (score 1):

A very short one just for the special case of 2 columns where you know that only one of them is populated and they are dates:

```
=ArrayFormula(to_date(if(D2:D,B2:B+C2:C,)))
```

[image]

Maybe the simplest formula which behaves like coalesce would be

```
=iferror(if(D2,hlookup(9^9,B2:C2,1,true),))
```

It's just a pull-down formula but will pick up the first non-blank column from a range of columns containing numbers or dates. If the columns are all blank, it returns blank.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

`=QUERY(transpose(B1:H1),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null limit 1",0)`

This transposes the row into a column, queries all non-null values from that column, and then set `limit 1` to return the first value.   So essentially you are selecting the leftmost non-empty value from your row.

I can't take full credit for this, I must have gotten it somewhere else... but it's in one of my sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column after Status call it Time (column E), whereas each formula follows this format (assuming your table starts at A3:E)

```
=if(A4="","",if(B4<>"",B4,C4))
```

Now query A3:E like so,

```
=query(A3:E,"Select A,E where D=TRUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the either or situation and [concat](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)enate the 2 columns.

```
=filter({A2:A,concat(B2:B,C2:C)},D2:D)
```

Also see local [array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) and [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)